# What's happening here "builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_proxy_pool'"?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website with scrapy. My code works fine but not in python3-venv.

I found  following error "builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_proxy_pool'" I search in google some says it python3.8.5 bugs but I am not sure what's happening.

I also notice something says "builtins.TypeError: _findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Here is all CLI output.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run in the env enviroment:

```
pip3 install scrapy_proxy_pool
```

on windows, or

```
sudo pip3 install scrapy_proxy_pool
```

if you are on linux.

Comment: Surprisingly It outputs "sudo: pip3: command not found"

Comment: try this before `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: It solved my first problem and now I am facing another one. When I run my program it outputs "Proxy is detected". Any farther help please....

Comment: ask another question, we want the community to find the answer quick if they have a problem. And include your code.